# Way to dump the relations from Freebase?

Tags: nlp, semantic-web, freebase, dbpedia, wikidata

I have ran through the Google API for Freebase, but still confusing.
Is there simple way to dump the relations from Freebase?

> I want to dump **all entity-name-pair** with a specific relation (e.g. marry_with,  ...), and also want the chinese entity names.

Should I

- write MQL to query all entity satisfying the condition? (but the MQL service is going to be retired recently. )
- or dump all freebase and parse?
- or is there other API capable of doing this?
- or other KB (YAGO, DBpedia, wikidata) is more easier of doing this?

Which way is easier to work out.
Please shed me some direction . thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Freebase was retired and Wikidata is the recommended alternative](https://plus.google.com/109936836907132434202/posts/bu3z2wVqcQc).

You can use the [Wikidata Query API](http://wdq.wmflabs.org/api_documentation.html) to get entities with a specific property.

For instance, the query `http://wdq.wmflabs.org/api?q=CLAIM[26]` retrieves the IDs of all items having the property `spouse` (P26).

You can combine this with the [Wikidata API](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php), for instance to get labels and aliases in English for the first three items returned by the previous query:
`http://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q23|Q24|Q42&languages=en&props=labels|aliases`